# How to find a keyword in a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Users send in smses which must include a keyword. This keyword is then used to find a business.

The instruction is to use the keyword at the start of the sentence.

I know some users won't use the keyword at the beginning or will add tags (# @ -) or punctuation (keyword.) to the keyword.

What is an efficient way to look for this keyword and for the business?

My attempt:

```
scrubbed_message = msg.gsub("\"", "").gsub("\'", "").gsub("#", "").gsub("-", "").gsub(",", "").gsub(".", "").gsub("@", "").split.join(" ")
tag = scrubbed_msg.split[0]
 if @business = Business.where(tag: tag).first
  log_message(@business)
 else
  scrubbed_msg.split.each do |w|
  if @business = Business.where(tag: w).first
   log_message(@business)
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of which characters you want to remove from the string, I suggest to use a whitelist approach specifying which characters you want to keep, for example alphanumeric characters:

```
sms = "#keyword and the rest"
clean_sms = sms.scan(/[\p{Alnum}]+/)
# => ["keyword", "and", "the", "rest"]
```

And then, if I got right what you are trying to do, to find the business you are looking for you could do something like this:

```
first_existing_tag = clean_sms.find do |tag| 
  Business.exists?(tag: tag)
end

@business = Business.where(tag: first_existing_tag).first
log_message(@business)
```

Comment: Thanks I will definitely include this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Regexp` match to filter all unnecessary characters out of the `String`, then use `#reduce` method on the `Array` git from splitted string to get the first occurience of a record with *tag* field matched to a keyword, in the exmaple: *keyword, tag1, tag2*:

```
msg = "key.w,ord tag-1'\n\"tag2"
# => "key.w,ord tag-1'\n\"tag2"
scrubbed = msg.gsub(/[#'"\-\.,@]/, "").split
# => ["keyword", "tag1", "tag2"]
@business = scrubbed.reduce(nil) do| sum, tag |
   sum || Business.where(tag: tag).first
end
# => Record tag: keyword
# => Record tag: tag1 if on record with keyword found
```

Comment: Thanks but can you explain this code? What does reduce(nil) do and the point of sum??